# Creating shared_ptr from raw pointer

Tags: c++

I have a pointer to an object. I would like to store it in two containers which both have the ownership. So I think I would be good to make it a shared_ptr of C++0x. How could I convert a raw pointer to a shared_pointer?

```
typedef unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<classA>>MAP1;
MAP1 map1;
classA* obj = new classA();
map1[ID] = how could I store obj in map1??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 75):

You need to make sure you don't initialize both shared_ptr objects with the same raw pointer, or it will be deleted twice. A better (but still bad) way to do it:

```
classA* raw_ptr = new classA;
shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr(raw_ptr);

// or shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr = raw_ptr;

// ...

shared_ptr<classA> other_ptr(my_ptr);
// or shared_ptr<classA> other_ptr = my_ptr;
// WRONG: shared_ptr<classA> other_ptr(raw_ptr);
// ALSO WRONG: shared_ptr<classA> other_ptr = raw_ptr;
```

**WARNING**: the above code shows bad practice! `raw_ptr` simply should not exist as a variable. If you directly initialize your smart pointers with the result of `new`, you reduce your risk of accidentally initializing other smart pointers incorrectly. What you should do is:

```
shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr(new classA);

shared_ptr<classA> other_ptr(my_ptr);
```

What's nice is that the code is more concise as well.

**EDIT**

I should probably elaborate on how it would work with a map. If you had a raw pointer and two maps, you could do something similar to what I showed above.

```
unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<classA> > my_map;
unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<classA> > that_guys_map;

shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr(new classA);

my_map.insert(make_pair("oi", my_ptr));
that_guys_map.insert(make_pair("oi", my_ptr));
// or my_map["oi"].reset(my_ptr);
// or my_map["oi"] = my_ptr;
// so many choices!
```

Comment: Don;t expose the raw pointer in a variable. By doing that you give a maintainer an easier opportunity to screw up and put the RAW pointer into another shared pointer. Just use `my_ptr(new ClassA());` That way a maintainer has to do extra work to screw things up.

Comment: @Martin York I was just editing to include a point about that; I'll add a more explicit note. But you are correct. :)

Comment: `// or shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr = raw_ptr;` is wrong in `std::shared_ptr`, because it should be explicit as `// or shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr(raw_ptr);`.

Comment: Actually, the best practice is make_shared<>, and avoiding new entirely. I can't remember the deep reason, something to do with if the new throws, I think it was in a Sean Parent talk.

Comment: @user1997744 You are nearly correct. If you use `shared_ptr<classA> my_ptr(new classA);`, (1) the `new classA` works, (2) the `new` within the `shared_ptr<>` fails, then the pointer allocated in (1) is lost. The `std::make_shared<>` handles that case properly (i.e. it has a `try/catch` block).

Comment: I'm very late here :v but if you are maintaining old code, with functions that return allocated pointers, the bad practice is the "safest" way :(

Comment: Comments are understandable... BUT when writing a code that has to interface with systems and your code is passed a raw pointer from software outside your control AND the specification says you must delete the pointer when done with it (which could be a long time later - then using a shared_ptr within your code, initialized with the externally provided raw pointer seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a variety of ways, but reset() would be good:

```
map1[ID].reset(obj);
```

And to address the issue of having two maps refer to the same shared_ptr, we can have:

```
map2[ID] = map1[ID];
```

Note that the trick in general to avoid a double delete is to try to avoid raw pointers at all.
Hence avoid:

```
classA* obj = new classA();
map1[ID].reset(obj);
```

but instead put the new heap object straight into a shared_ptr.

Comment: it's not bad practise per se, it's c-practice!