# C++ use shared_ptr for continuous allocated memory

Tags: c++

I want to create some continuous memory, and use bunch of shared_ptr pointing to them.

```
int main() {
  int *arr = new int[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(&arr[i]);
  }// when the loop scope end, the shared_ptr will be destroyed. 
};
```

this code will give an error:

```
pointer being freed was not allocated
```

my expectation: when the scope of loop end, the shared_ptr will be destroy, and the element in array will be destroyed successively.

But it seems that when the first pointer is destroyed, the whole array is freed.

I also tried `std::allocator`, still not work.

So is there any way that can allocate continuous memory, and I can use shared_ptr pointing to each of them, then when the first element is freed, the whole memory won't be freed together?

Comment: Please show any code which frees anything. Some of it seems wrong. Maybe directly try for a [mcve].

Comment: *Why* do you want to use a shared pointer to a single element? What is the *actual* problem you try to solve? And if you had [read about `std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) you would know that it tries to `delete` the memory it wraps.

Comment: @Yunnosch That would be the `ptr` object going out of scope at the end of each loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating shared\_ptr from raw pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665266/creating-shared-ptr-from-raw-pointer)

Comment: An allocation cannot be deallocated in pieces, and that's what storing pointers to different pieces of a single allocation in smart pointers would do. You could have a wrapper that contained a shared pointer to the whole array and a reference to a specific element. This way all of the shared pointers to the array must die before the array will be freed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its an "interesting" thing to want to do but if you really want to do it you can use the `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor.

```
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[5]);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(arr,&arr[i]);
  }
};
```

Without c++17 you need to do a little more:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[5], std::default_delete<int[]> {});
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(arr, &arr.get()[i]);
    }
};
```

The array will be deleted when the last element `shared_ptr` is destroyed (assuming the array `shared_ptr` itself has already been destroyed/reset).

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing `shared_ptr`. The memory you allocated was attributed with `operator new[]`, it should thus be freed with `operator delete[]`.

Furthermore, since the allocated object is an array, any ownership semantics should be applied to the whole array and not divided across its elements!

You can achieve by specifying a custom deleter for your `shared_ptr`: (C++11/14)

```
std::shared_ptr<int> arr_ptr(new int[5], std::default_delete<int[]> {});
```

Or simply using an array type specialization of `shared_ptr` (C++17):

```
std::shared_ptr<int[]> arr_ptr(new int[5]); // Will call delete[] upon destruction.
```

Comment: [The correct way to use a shared pointer to an array is like `std::shared_ptr<int[]>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/1171191).

Comment: @BoBTFish That's what I tried first, but to no avail: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/106828ec577354cf

Comment: @Rerito I smell outdated Clang on Coliru. It works on GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9bd51b8056a6f5f

Comment: Alright, integrated the C++17 solution to the answer!

Comment: Fair point, it's a bit early to assume C++17 support everywhere. Good to show both options.

Comment: And in C++20, you can use `std::shared_ptr<int[]> arr_ptr = std::make_shared<int[]>(5);` instead of calling `new int[5]` separately and risk a leak if the `shared_ptr` constructor throws an exception.